# Redirect user to prev page when going to wp/login.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a login/register popup plugin for auth flow but the default form is still open. Plugin Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-login-woocommerce/

This plugin requires user's first name, last name, username, email, password, and agreement to terms and conditions. The default form doesn't require all of the fields as above.

In order to keep consistent info about all members, I am trying to redirect people who go to /wp-login.php, /wp-login.php?action=register, /wp-login.php?action=lostpassword to previous page and add "#login" to that page's link.

Adding #login or #register to link brings up the login/register popup.

I am trying to write a function that I can add to custom plugin file. Below is what I have so far but I am not sure how to get the link and add #login to it. Also, I am not sure if I am using the correct hook.

```
function redirect_login_to_prev_page() {

    $restrictions = array(
        '/wp-admin/',
        '/wp-login.php*'
    );

    foreach ( $restrictions as $restriction ) {

        //get link of prev page
        //add #login to that link
        //redirect the user to that link

    }

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin_with_redirect' );
```

Also, is this a good way of doing this or should I do something else?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that should work for you. Place this in the functions.php file of your child theme or use any snippets plugin and add this in that plugin.

```
// Hook the appropriate WordPress action
add_action('init', 'redirect_wp_login');

function redirect_wp_login() {
    // WP tracks the current page - global variable to access it
    global $pagenow;
    
    // Check if we're on the login page
    if($pagenow == 'wp-login.php' && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
        $previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
        // Redirect with #login added
        wp_redirect($previous.'#login');
        // Stop execution to prevent the page from loading for any reason
        exit();
    }
}
```